# subprocess gives an error. "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, oracle, subprocess, sqlplus

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import requests

from bs4 import *
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import os

connectString = 'SYSTEM/mediadot123'

def runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString):
   session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   session.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
   return session.communicate()

session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','hr/hr'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate()

sqlCommand = "insert into food(title, recipe, image) values ('bla','bla','bla');"
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString)
print queryResult
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Umer/PycharmProjects/DATACRAWLER/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Umer/PycharmProjects/DATACRAWLER/main.py", line 38, in <module>

session = subprocess.Popen(['sqlplus','-S','hr/hr'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Is sqlplus in your PATH? Have you tried substituting `'sqlplus'` with the absolute path to sqlplus?

Comment: Can you please tell  me what PATH should i add?

Comment: Where is the `sqlplus` executable on your filesystem? E.g. if it's `C:\Program Files\Oracle\sqlplus.exe` add `C:\Program Files\Oracle\` to your PATH. Easier yet, just replace `'sqlplus'` with `'C:\Program Files\Oracle\sqlplus.exe'`

Comment: I use SQPLUS through cmd only and there is no executable file in my ORACLE folder. Plus, i have run the same code on my computer but when i run the same code in my remote desktop; it gives this error.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g enterprise edition on both and both are x64

Comment: @UmerJaved Run (in cmd.exe): `where sqlplus` and you'll get the path. Then use that path in your `Popen(['C:/path/sqlplus.exe', '-S', ...])`

Comment: in 11g; you have only access through command line and its running perfectly when I type 'sqlplus' in there. This means that sqlplus is in my PATH right?

Comment: @UmerJaved Maybe for that particular logged on user, yes. Might not be available for every user/environment. Depends on which "`PATH`" it's set up in. you can check via `print(os.environ['PATH'])`.

Comment: @UmerJaved Pleasure is all mine. Someone might post a better answer later on but don't forget to mark your question as solved for now so we don't leave any solved questions in the unanswered pile here on Stack Overflow. Neat and tidy is a nice environment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an absolute path for your command-execution.
Some binaries are not located in `PATH` depending on your user, system and software installation.

To find out where `sqlplus` resides, run the following in `cmd.exe`: `where sqlplus` and that should give you the absolute path.

Then simply do:

```
Popen(['C:/path/sqlplus.exe', '-S', ...])
```

Also to find out what's actually in your `PATH` environment variable, you could do the following:

```
print(os.environ['PATH'])
```